# Show that $y=a \log \sec{(x/a)}$ has no oblique asymptote and the only vertical asymptotes are $x=(2n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{2})a, ~~n=\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, asymptotics

Show that $y=a \log \sec{(x/a)}$ has no oblique asymptote and the **only asymptotes** are the vertical asymptotes are $$x=(2n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{2})a, ~~n=\mathbb{Z}$$

How to show that it has no oblique asymptote? What is $$\lim_{x\to \infty}(y/x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}a \frac{\log \sec{(x/a)}}{x}=...$$

Also $y$ is defined if $\sec{(x/a)}>0$ but how to find the vertical and horizontal asymptotes? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No Slant Asymptotes

If an [oblique asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) of form $y=mx+b$, $m\neq0,$ for a given function $f(x)$ exists, then it can be computed via
\begin{align}
m&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{x}\\
n&=\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-mx)
\end{align}
where $c=\pm\infty$.

Assume that $y=a\log⁡\sec⁡(x/a)$ has an oblique asymptote, and consider the $c=\infty$ case. Then

$$m=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a\log⁡\sec⁡(x/a)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-a\log⁡\cos⁡(x/a)}{x}=0.$$

Some rationale behind how this works: This limit could only be non-zero in the case that $\log⁡\cos⁡(x/a)\to\pm\infty$. The function $\log(x)$ only tends to $\infty$ if $x\to 0,\infty$. The expression $\cos(x/a)$ never reaches $\infty$. It is bounded above by 1, meaning $0\geq\log⁡\cos⁡(x/a)$. The expression $\cos(x/a)$ generally does equal $0$ for certain values of $x$, however, we've restricted $\sec(x/a)>0$, implying that $\cos(x/a)>0$. We now have that $\log⁡\cos⁡(x/a)>-\infty$. Taken together, we have that

$$0\geq\log(\cos(x/a))>-\infty.$$

This indicates that, $x$ in the denominator tends to infinity, while the top is bounded, and the limit is $0$.

Returning to our slant asymptote issue, recall that we require that $m\neq0$ for an oblique asymptote to exist. Therefore no oblique asymptote exists as we move towards $+\infty$. A similar argument applies for $c=-\infty$.

### Vertical Asymptotes

A vertical asymptote of a function $f(x)$ at $x=b$ satisfies

1. $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=\pm\infty$ or
2. $\lim_{x\to b^{+}}f(x)=\pm\infty$.

Now we find the locations $x=b$ that can satisfy one of the above relationships.

$$\lim_{x\to b^{-}}a\log⁡\sec⁡(x/a)=\pm\infty.$$

Some of the same reasoning is used as in the above section. $\log(x)$ can only tend to infinity if $x\to 0$ or $\infty$. Then we ask ourselves, when does $\sec(x/a)\to 0$ or $\infty$? There exists no $x$ where $\sec(x/a)=0$, however, if $x/a\to\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$, $\sec(x/a)\to\infty$. Any multiple of $2\pi$ added to these angles also gives values that work. This implies that $x/a=\pm\pi/2+2\pi n$. Multiply by $a$ on both sides to obtain the result you posted.

### Horizontal Asymptotes

The horizontal line $y = c$ is a horizontal asymptote of the function $y = f(x)$ if

1. $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=c$ or
2. $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=c.$

If we attempt take $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}y$, we notice that the limit is oscillatory, and does not converge, so no horizontal asymptotes exist.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}a\log⁡\sec⁡(x/a)=\pm\infty.$ when + and when - will occur?